# jQuery UI - Sortable List - limited Items - special behaviour

Tags: jquery, list, user-interface, max

I'm working for the first time with jQuery UI. For my current project the sortable-function comes very handy. Im trying to build some kind of playlist-editor. There is a bunch of tracks (list 1) and the user shall be able to drag and drop them to a playlist with max 3 items (list 2). 
I already managed to set the max of 3 items, but with my current solution there is no way to sort the items within the single lists. When the max of 3 items in the playlist ist reached, I still want the user to sort or remove one of the list-items.

Would you give me a hint?

```
$(function() {   $( "#playlist, #tracks" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".mix",
    cursor: "move",
    handle: ".handle",
    revert: 200,
    opacity: 0.8,
    delay: 50,
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var size = $("#playlist li.track").size();
        $("#music").append(size+" ");
        sizeCheck();
        if (playlistFull) {
            $("#music").append("full ");
            } else { 
            $("#music").append("space ");
            };
        playlistWatcher();
        },
    start: function(event, ui) {
        if (playlistFull) {
            // $(ui.item).sortable('cancel');  // What to do here?
            };
        },
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9yzea/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI draggable/sortable/droppable disable drop when droppable limit is reached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539708/jquery-ui-draggable-sortable-droppable-disable-drop-when-droppable-limit-is-reac)

Comment: This does exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3673837/221061. In your `sort` event, bind the `sortreceive` handler when the item count hits your max. Also in the `sort` event, unbind the `sortreceive` handler if the item count falls below your max.

Comment: In the current documentation I can't find any "sortreceive" handler. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It's there. See the link I posted, it shows you exactly what to do

Comment: Ok, well. Now it doesn't accept a 4th item in the Playlist anymore, but while dragging it still makes room for it (suggesting to drop it). Only when actually dropping the item, it gets thrown back. Thats not exactly the behaviour I would like to achieve. I want it to tell its full already while hovering a 4th item. What event to choose?

Comment: Just added the whole thing to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9yzea/ 
"globalEval" doesn't seem to work here, but you get the idea.